# Non Persistent Core data Model

Tags: ios, core-data

I have 2 api calls in my application. Both of them are supposed to return an array of objects of same type in completion handler. I need to persist response from one API but not the other. I am using Core data to persist data in SQLite database. So the return type of this API is an array of Core data model objects.

Now here is the problem. Second api response does not need to be persisted on Database. But since I need to return same model object, I am forced to create an array of Managed Objects and return it in completion handler of second API. This is causing many unexpected behaviours in my application.

I do not need to persist second api response in any case. But I need the same model to be returned in response of both API's. Is this possible?